# How to resolve the promise and return the data back to where it was called?

Tags: node.js, promise

I am really struggling with how to get the results of getAVPPlayerInfo() returned to the place where it is called (from the generatePlayersArray function on this line: `var avpinfo = getAVPPlayerInfo(pinfo);`

I've been using the code before this without generatePlayersArray() and getAVPPlayerInfo(), but the player data didn't need to be updated before.  I have seen people change the line to `var avpinfo = await getAVPPlayerInfo(pinfo);` but that doesn't fix the problem.

How can I change this to fix the disconnect between these two functions?

```
  // creates an order with all cart items and user info
    var userNewOrder = function(charge, cart, callback) {
      console.log('Saving customer ORDER for charge', charge.id);
      Order.create({
        cart: {
          username: cart.username,
          items: cart.items,
          totalQty: cart.totalQty,
          totalPrice: cart.totalPrice
        },
        customer: cart.customerID,
        paymentID: charge.id,
        createdOn: new Date(),
        paymentStatus: 'PAID',
        user: cart.username
      })
        .then(function(order) {
          console.log('Order created!', order._id);
          saveUserRegistrations(order, callback);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('Error creating order', err);
          callback(err);
        });
    };

    // manipulate the data to prepare for registration data
    var saveUserRegistrations = function(order, callback) {
      console.log('Saving registrations from order', order.id);
      //put cart items into array of objects
      var registrations = generateRegistrationsArray(order);
      // console.log("Registrations ",registrations);
      var paymentId = order.paymentID;
      var userobject = order.user;
      // add paymentid to arrays
      for (var i in registrations) {
        registrations[i].paymentID = paymentId;
        registrations[i].users = userobject;
        for (var x in registrations[i].players) {
          console.log(registrations[i].players[x]);
        }
      }
      console.log(
        'Registrations with payment ID and username added',
        registrations
      );
      saveRegistrations(registrations, callback);
    };

    // generates the registrations array from the cart items
    var generateRegistrationsArray = function(order) {
      console.log('Generating array from cart items');
      var arr = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < order.cart.items.length; i++) {
        var players = generatePlayersArray(order.cart.items[i]);
        console.log('Players: ', players);
        // create registration, using new players array
        arr.push({
          event: order.cart.items[i].event,
          field: order.cart.items[i].field,
          day: order.cart.items[i].day,
          division: order.cart.items[i].division,
          level: order.cart.items[i].level,
          group: order.cart.items[i].group,
          numplayers: order.cart.items[i].numberofplayers,
          price: order.cart.items[i].price,
          players: players,
          createdOn: new Date(),
          net: null,
          team: null,
          notes: null,
          paymentNote: null,
          waiversSent: false,
          reviewed: false,
          active: true
        });
        console.log('Registrations:', arr);
      }
      console.log('Registrations array', JSON.stringify(arr));
      return arr;
    };

    // generates the player array from the cart and AVP info
    var generatePlayersArray = function(items) {
      console.log('Generating players array from cart items');
      var parr = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < items.players.length; i++) {
        var pinfo = {
          last: items.players[i].last,
          avp_id: items.players[i].avp_id
        };
        var avpinfo = getAVPPlayerInfo(pinfo);
        console.log('AVP info returned', avpinfo);
        // create registration, using new players array
        parr.push({
          first: avpinfo.first || items.players[i].first,
          last: avpinfo.last || items.players[i].last,
          email: items.players[i].email,
          address: avpinfo.address || items.players[i].address,
          city: avpinfo.city || items.players[i].city,
          state: avpinfo.state || items.players[i].state,
          zip: avpinfo.zip || items.players[i].zip,
          country: items.players[i].country,
          phone: avpinfo.phone || items.players[i].phone,
          signed: false,
          sandbagger: false,
          waivers: [],
          createdOn: new Date(),
          adult: avpinfo.adult || items.players[i].adult,
          avp_id: items.players[i].avp_id,
          ranking: items.players[i].ranking,
          overallRanking: items.players[i].overallRanking,
          shirt_size: items.players[i].shirtSize
        });
        console.log(parr);
      }
      console.log('Players array', JSON.stringify(parr));
      return parr;
    };

    // get AVP data to update player info
    var getAVPPlayerInfo = function(pinfo) {
      console.log('Admin AVP API begin', pinfo);
      avp_id = pinfo.avp_id;
      last = pinfo.last;
      // GET THE AVP DATA
      var options = {
        uri: `http://api.volleyamerica.com/VAREST.svc/V6rHHdPO/players/${avp_id}`,
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
        },
        json: true // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
      };

      rp(options)
        .then(function(resp) {
          console.log('Player has data', resp);
          let avp = {};
          let address = resp.Address1 || null;
          if (resp.Address2) {
            address += ` ${resp.Address2}`;
          }
          // GET AVP member data (shirt size and ranking for db)
          avp.avp_id = avp_id;
          avp.shirtSize = resp.AdultShirtSize;
          avp.first = resp.FirstName;
          avp.last = resp.LastName;
          avp.email = resp.Email || null;
          avp.phone = resp.HomePhone || null;
          avp.address = address || null;
          avp.signed = false;
          avp.sandbagger = false;
          avp.waivers = [];
          avp.city = resp.City || null;
          avp.state = resp.State || null;
          avp.zip = resp.Zip || null;
          // get overallRankings greater than 0
          avp.overallRanking = _.pickBy(
            _.get(resp, 'OverallRanking', {}),
            (ranking, key) => {
              return ranking > 0;
            }
          );
          // get rankings greater than 0
          avp.ranking = _.pickBy(_.get(resp, 'Ranking', {}), (ranking, key) => {
            return ranking > 0;
          });
          let adult = null;
          // if player is under 18
          const birthday = moment(resp.Birthdate, 'M/D/YYYY');
          age = moment().diff(birthday, 'years', false);
          if (age < 18) {
            avp.adult = false;
          } else {
            avp.adult = true;
          }
          console.log('AVP API SUCCESS, returning avp data ', avp);
          return avp;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('AVP data error', err);
        });
    };

    //save registrations to the database
    var saveRegistrations = function(registrations, callback) {
      console.log('SAVING REGISTRATIONS TO DB', registrations);
      // var reginfo = registrations;
      Registration.collection
        .insert(registrations)
        .then(function(r) {
          console.log('Successfully saved registrations!', r.insertedCount);
          nodemailerConfirmation(registrations, callback);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          for (var i in err.writeErrors) {
            console.log(err.writeErrors[i].errmsg);
          }

          callback(err.message);
        });
    };
```

Comment: Please note, this is only a part of my callback function.  They say to only post the parts relevant to the question, so I left the functions before and after these out of the post.

Comment: If you return the `rp(options)` in the `getAVPPlayerInfo` function, you could either `await` it or wrap the necessary logic in a `then` block.  You are doing that in a loop, so you might even look into turning that chunk into individual promises and do a `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 0):

```
// creates an order with all cart items and user info
    var userNewOrder = function(charge, cart, callback) {
      console.log('Saving customer ORDER for charge', charge.id);
      Order.create({
        cart: {
          username: cart.username,
          items: cart.items,
          totalQty: cart.totalQty,
          totalPrice: cart.totalPrice
        },
        customer: cart.customerID,
        paymentID: charge.id,
        createdOn: new Date(),
        paymentStatus: 'PAID',
        user: cart.username
      })
        .then(function(order) {
          console.log('Order created!', order._id);
          saveUserRegistrations(order, callback);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('Error creating order', err);
          callback(err);
        });
    };

    // manipulate the data to prepare for registration data
    var saveUserRegistrations = async function(order, callback) {
      console.log('Saving registrations from order', order.id);
      //put cart items into array of objects
      var registrations = await generateRegistrationsArray(order);
      // console.log("Registrations ",registrations);
      var paymentId = order.paymentID;
      var userobject = order.user;
      // add paymentid to arrays
      for (var i in registrations) {
        registrations[i].paymentID = paymentId;
        registrations[i].users = userobject;
        for (var x in registrations[i].players) {
          console.log(registrations[i].players[x]);
        }
      }
      console.log(
        'Registrations with payment ID and username added',
        registrations
      );
      saveRegistrations(registrations, callback);
    };

    // generates the registrations array from the cart items
    var generateRegistrationsArray = async function(order) {
      console.log('Generating array from cart items');
      var arr = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < order.cart.items.length; i++) {
        var players = await generatePlayersArray(order.cart.items[i]);
        console.log('Players: ', players);
        // create registration, using new players array
        arr.push({
          event: order.cart.items[i].event,
          field: order.cart.items[i].field,
          day: order.cart.items[i].day,
          division: order.cart.items[i].division,
          level: order.cart.items[i].level,
          group: order.cart.items[i].group,
          numplayers: order.cart.items[i].numberofplayers,
          price: order.cart.items[i].price,
          players: players,
          createdOn: new Date(),
          net: null,
          team: null,
          notes: null,
          paymentNote: null,
          waiversSent: false,
          reviewed: false,
          active: true
        });
        console.log('Registrations:', arr);
      }
      console.log('Registrations array', JSON.stringify(arr));
      return arr;
    };

    // generates the player array from the cart and AVP info
    var generatePlayersArray = async function(items) {
      console.log('Generating players array from cart items');
      var parr = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < items.players.length; i++) {
        var pinfo = {
          last: items.players[i].last,
          avp_id: items.players[i].avp_id
        };
        var avpinfo = await getAVPPlayerInfo(pinfo);
        console.log('AVP info returned', avpinfo);
        // create registration, using new players array
        parr.push({
          first: avpinfo.first || items.players[i].first,
          last: avpinfo.last || items.players[i].last,
          email: items.players[i].email,
          address: avpinfo.address || items.players[i].address,
          city: avpinfo.city || items.players[i].city,
          state: avpinfo.state || items.players[i].state,
          zip: avpinfo.zip || items.players[i].zip,
          country: items.players[i].country,
          phone: avpinfo.phone || items.players[i].phone,
          signed: false,
          sandbagger: false,
          waivers: [],
          createdOn: new Date(),
          adult: avpinfo.adult || items.players[i].adult,
          avp_id: items.players[i].avp_id,
          ranking: items.players[i].ranking,
          overallRanking: items.players[i].overallRanking,
          shirt_size: items.players[i].shirtSize
        });
        console.log(parr);
      }
      console.log('Players array', JSON.stringify(parr));
      return parr;
    };

    // get AVP data to update player info
    var getAVPPlayerInfo = function(pinfo) {
      console.log('Admin AVP API begin', pinfo);
      avp_id = pinfo.avp_id;
      last = pinfo.last;
      // GET THE AVP DATA
      var options = {
        uri: `http://api.volleyamerica.com/VAREST.svc/V6rHHdPO/players/${avp_id}`,
        headers: {
          'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
        },
        json: true // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
      };

      rp(options)
        .then(function(resp) {
          console.log('Player has data', resp);
          let avp = {};
          let address = resp.Address1 || null;
          if (resp.Address2) {
            address += ` ${resp.Address2}`;
          }
          // GET AVP member data (shirt size and ranking for db)
          avp.avp_id = avp_id;
          avp.shirtSize = resp.AdultShirtSize;
          avp.first = resp.FirstName;
          avp.last = resp.LastName;
          avp.email = resp.Email || null;
          avp.phone = resp.HomePhone || null;
          avp.address = address || null;
          avp.signed = false;
          avp.sandbagger = false;
          avp.waivers = [];
          avp.city = resp.City || null;
          avp.state = resp.State || null;
          avp.zip = resp.Zip || null;
          // get overallRankings greater than 0
          avp.overallRanking = _.pickBy(
            _.get(resp, 'OverallRanking', {}),
            (ranking, key) => {
              return ranking > 0;
            }
          );
          // get rankings greater than 0
          avp.ranking = _.pickBy(_.get(resp, 'Ranking', {}), (ranking, key) => {
            return ranking > 0;
          });
          let adult = null;
          // if player is under 18
          const birthday = moment(resp.Birthdate, 'M/D/YYYY');
          age = moment().diff(birthday, 'years', false);
          if (age < 18) {
            avp.adult = false;
          } else {
            avp.adult = true;
          }
          console.log('AVP API SUCCESS, returning avp data ', avp);
          return avp;
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log('AVP data error', err);
        });
    };

    //save registrations to the database
    var saveRegistrations = function(registrations, callback) {
      console.log('SAVING REGISTRATIONS TO DB', registrations);
      // var reginfo = registrations;
      Registration.collection
        .insert(registrations)
        .then(function(r) {
          console.log('Successfully saved registrations!', r.insertedCount);
          nodemailerConfirmation(registrations, callback);
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          for (var i in err.writeErrors) {
            console.log(err.writeErrors[i].errmsg);
          }

          callback(err.message);
        });
    };
```

Check the above code.